# What's the difference between `Eclipse/Project/Clean...` and `Eclipse/Project/Refresh (F5)`?

Tags: java, eclipse

What's the difference between

```
"Eclipse/Project/Clean..."
```

and

```
"Eclipse/Project/Refresh (F5)"
```

I often have to "rebuild" my workspace that contains few inter-dependent projects, and I am unsure which is the best way to make a clean start?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As mentioned [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/104846/vc/Eclipse-refresh-vs-clean)

`Refresh` analyses the source-files to check if any changes were made from outside Eclipse, and if so, compiles files that were changed.

`Clean` on the other hand removes **all** compiled classes and forces recompilation of the whole project (or workspace).

Comment: Mention the source as well... :) http://www.coderanch.com/t/104846/vc/Eclipse-refresh-vs-clean

Comment: Clean will trigger a build only of auto build is enabled.

Comment: Refresh only causes compilation if you have automatic builds enabled.  All it's doing is updating their state as Eclipse knows them--if that means it's considered changed since the last time Eclipse looked at it, then it needs to built and will be built whenever the next build occurs, which might be automatic or not.

Answer (score 3):

**Clean** deleted the generated resources like compiled classes and makes sure that latest code base is recompiled again where as

**Refresh** syncs the eclipse project from the actual folder structure which makes sure that any changes done to files and/or folder structure is available to eclipse...

Answer (score 1):

**Clean** will clean all the compiled files from the selected projects. It will trigger a rebuild if **Build Automatically** (in the project menu) is enabled.

**Refresh** will reload the files in the project from the filesystem.

For your question, **Clean** will be the answer. Make sure that you have **Build Automatically** checked.